# ASMX web-service-call The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized

Tags: runtime-error, http-status-code-401

In an Episerver-project a call is made from a website on one server to an ASMX-webservice at another server. 
The user calling has all right set in IIS 7 to write, create and retrieve files from folders.

The following error-message appears when this call is made:

```
RemotePublishForLedigeStillinger.DataFactoryService.RawPage rawPageLedigeStillingerRemote = dfService.GetDefaultPageData(pageRef, Int32.Parse(pageidOfLedigeStillingar));
```

How can I resolve the following error?:

```
Detailed error information (authorized by permissions to functions)
Error occured   01.10.2012 14:35:07
User IP 172.29.2.84
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1
Url ....
Referer ...

The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.]
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall) +431289
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters) +204
   RemotePublishForLedigeStillinger.DataFactoryService.DataFactoryService.GetDefaultPageData(PageReference pageLink, Int32 pageTypeID) in C:\Programmering\RemotePublishTest\RemotePublishTest\Web References\DataFactoryService\Reference.cs:147
   RemotePublishForLedigeStillinger.Program.PublishPageToRemoteService(PageData pageLedigeStillingerOriginal) in C:\Programmering\RemotePublishTest\RemotePublishTest\Program.cs:143
   EPiServer.Templates.RelatePlus.Pages.JobAd.RemotePublishPage(PageData pageToPublish) in C:\Repo\Projects\dikt.intranett\www\Templates\RelatePlus\Pages\JobAd.aspx.cs:125
   EPiServer.Templates.RelatePlus.Pages.JobAd.Godkjent_OnClick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Repo\Projects\dikt.intranett\www\Templates\RelatePlus\Pages\JobAd.aspx.cs:110
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +110
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565
```

The IIS-log shows this:

```
2002:5100:9dbc:8000:0:5efe:10.50.0.227, -, 10/1/2012, 14:52:20, W3SVC2, DRINVS253, 2002:5100:9dbc:8000:0:5efe:10.50.0.160, 15, 775, 1700, 401, 0, POST, /WebServices/DataFactoryService.asmx, -,
2002:5100:9dbc:8000:0:5efe:10.50.0.227, dr-2\epi.admin, 10/1/2012, 14:52:20, W3SVC2, DRINVS253, 2002:5100:9dbc:8000:0:5efe:10.50.0.160, 0, 806, 1700, 401, 0, POST, /WebServices/DataFactoryService.asmx, -,
```

Some data from web.config at the server on which the webservice is deployed.:

```
<episerver.basicAuthentication sendBasicChallenge="true" basicRealm="" />
    <system.web>
      <httpModules>
    <add 
        name="BasicAuthentication" 
        type="EPiServer.Security.BasicAuthentication, EPiServer" /> 

   </httpModules> 

      <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1000000" />
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Administrators,WebServices,dr-2\epi.admin" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>

        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
         <add name="BasicAuthentication" type="EPiServer.Security.BasicAuthentication, EPiServer" />
        </modules> 

    <handlers>
        <clear />
        <add name="webresources" path="WebResource.axd" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader" />
        <add name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated" path="*.asmx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory, System.Web.Services, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="integratedMode" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
        <add name="wildcard" path="*" verb="*" type="EPiServer.Web.StaticFileHandler, EPiServer" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
```

Addition:
The user is 'dr-2\epi-admin'.

Its login-details are sent to the server:

```
public DataFactoryService() {
    this.Url = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[urlForLedigeStillingerRemoteServiceStringFromAppSettingsGlobal];
    this.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        //.Default.RemotePublishForLedigeStillinger_DataFactoryService_DataFactoryService;
    if ((this.IsLocalFileSystemWebService(this.Url) == true)) {
        this.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        this.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly = false;
    }
    else {
        this.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly = true;
    }
}
```

After removing the 'deny'-tag the request are further processed and I know receive this error:

> or occured    01.10.2012 15:39:56 User IP 172.29.2.84 User
>   Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101
>   Firefox/15.0.1
>   Url   [Url removed]
>
> Referer   [Url removed]
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to
>   process request. ---> EPiServer.Core.EPiServerException: The user does
>   not have the 'Permission.WebServiceAccess' access right to access web
>   services on the remote site, for user    at
>   EPiServer.WebServices.DataFactoryService.ValidateWebServiceAccess()
>   at
>   EPiServer.WebServices.DataFactoryService.GetDefaultPageData(PageReference
>   pageLink, Int32 pageTypeID)   --- End of inner exception stack trace
>   ---  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException:
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to
>   process request. ---> EPiServer.Core.EPiServerException: The user does
>   not have the 'Permission.WebServiceAccess' access right to access web
>   services on the remote site, for user    at
>   EPiServer.WebServices.DataFactoryService.ValidateWebServiceAccess()
>   at
>   EPiServer.WebServices.DataFactoryService.GetDefaultPageData(PageReference
>
> ### pageLink, Int32 pageTypeID)   --- End of inner exception stack trace
>
> Source Error:  An unhandled exception was generated during the
>   execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin
>   and location of the exception can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SoapException: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server
>   was unable to process request. ---> EPiServer.Core.EPiServerException:
>   The user does not have the 'Permission.WebServiceAccess' access right
>   to access web services on the remote site, for user     at
>   EPiServer.WebServices.DataFactoryService.ValidateWebServiceAccess()
>   at
>   EPiServer.WebServices.DataFactoryService.GetDefaultPageData(PageReference
>   pageLink, Int32 pageTypeID)    --- End of inner exception stack trace
>   ---]    System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage
>   message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean
>   asyncCall) +431766
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] parameters) +204
>   RemotePublishForLedigeStillinger.DataFactoryService.DataFactoryService.GetDefaultPageData(PageReference
>   pageLink, Int32 pageTypeID) in
>   C:\Programmering\RemotePublishTest\RemotePublishTest\Web
>   References\DataFactoryService\Reference.cs:148
>   RemotePublishForLedigeStillinger.Program.PublishPageToRemoteService(PageData
>   pageLedigeStillingerOriginal) in
>   C:\Programmering\RemotePublishTest\RemotePublishTest\Program.cs:143
>   EPiServer.Templates.RelatePlus.Pages.JobAd.RemotePublishPage(PageData
>   pageToPublish) in
>   C:\Repo\Projects\dikt.intranett\www\Templates\RelatePlus\Pages\JobAd.aspx.cs:125
>   EPiServer.Templates.RelatePlus.Pages.JobAd.Godkjent_OnClick(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in
>   C:\Repo\Projects\dikt.intranett\www\Templates\RelatePlus\Pages\JobAd.aspx.cs:110
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +110
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +36    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +1565

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, it looks to me as though the anonymous user and/or the identity for the application pool hosting the service does not have privileges to enumerate the group dr-2\epi.admin, specified in the "roles...allow" block of your configuration file...or the calling user identity is in none of those roles, and the default deny rule applies.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
According to the IIS-log it is the user dr-2\epi.admin accessing the web service. So would that have any affect?

Comment: DOH on me, I misread the log file portion of the post. Are you certain that dr-2\epi.admin truly has permissions to the service? Looks to me like the identity is negotiated, but permission is still being denied, which initially points to a basic configuration problem for the files in the service.

Comment: Thanks! I removed the 'deny'-tag, and now the request was processed further. I now receive the following [I updated my post to include all details.]: 
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> EPiServer.Core.EPiServerException: The user does not have the 'Permission.WebServiceAccess' access right to access web services on the remote site, for user 
  at EPiServer.WebServices.DataFactoryService.ValidateWebServiceAccess()

Comment: This appears to be an error related specifically to the Epicenter system. I did a little redding and it seems there a security configuration pertaining to function access and granting users permissions to channels in a configuration management tool. Hope that helps; I'm otherwise not familiar with Epicenter..

Comment: Thanks! I had already tried that solution.
The problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: @AndersBranderud, I'm facing the same issue. May I know the solution ?